# IDEA GDSL How to add a method defination to all files(Classes) in a folder?

Tags: intellij-idea, dsl

In my Grails Application, there a folder **grails-app/mongoDomain**. In this folder there are several classes that too in various packages.

I want to add a GDSL Defination for a method say "save()" to all classes inside the folder **grails-app/mongoDomain**.

I was successfully able to add this method to a single class, but any method to add in all classes in **grails-app/mongoDomain**?? 
.
.
I tried Doing this, but it did't worked..

```
def mongoDomainContext = context(pathRegexp: /.*grails-app\/mongoDomain.*/)

contributor(mongoDomainContext) {
    method(name: 'save', type: 'void', params: [closure: { }])
}
```

But the above code did't worked, What is the right method for doing it??

.
.
Regards
Kushal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such GDSL primitive yet. In Griffon, they have the following GDSL fragment using undocumented features:

```
['Controller', 'Model', 'View', 'Service'].each { type ->
String artifactPath = type.toLowerCase() + 's'
contributor(ctype: PsiJavaPatterns.psiClass().withName(PlatformPatterns.string().matches(/.*${type}/))) {
    def path = psiClass.containingFile.originalFile.virtualFile.path
    if (path =~ ".*/*griffon-app/${artifactPath}/.*") {
        delegatesTo(findClass("griffon.core.Griffon${type}"))

        if (type == 'View') {
            addNodeContributions(delegate)
        }
    }
}
```

}

They match on both class name and its path here, you need only the second part, inside the conributor call.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it and it works. Great thanks to *Peter Gromov* for providing the hint.

```
def mongoContext = context(
        ctype: PsiJavaPatterns.psiClass().withName(PlatformPatterns.string().matches(/.*/))
)

contributor(mongoContext) {
    def path = ""
    try {
        path = psiClass.containingFile.originalFile.virtualFile.path
    } catch (Exception e) {/*This is to prevent any non Class null matches*/}
    if (path =~ ".*/*grails-app/mongoDomain/.*")//Matches Directory 
    {
        //Code Here to add methods/Properties etc

    }
}
```

It worked like a charm. Thanks to all.